# How do I dismiss a popUp from within the popUp itself?

Tags: swiftui

I have a button that displays a PopUp when pressed, and on the PopUp is a button that is supposed to dismiss the PopUp itself.

I am unsure as to how to use @Binding variable here (if I am correct in assuming that's what I'm supposed to use to communicate between different structs)

```
struct TESTSTSTSTS: View {

    @State var showPopUp = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

        Button(action: {
            self.showPopUp = true
        }) {
            Text("Show PopUp Button")
        }

            Spacer()

            if self.showPopUp == true {
                PopUp()
            }


        }
    }
}


struct PopUp: View {


    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Color.orange

        Button(action: {
            //Unsure what code to  use here.
        }) {
            Text("Hide PopUp Button")
            }

        }.frame(width: 300, height: 500, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Binding is indeed a possibility to solve this.

It works like this:

```
struct ContentView : View {
    @State var showPopUp = false

    var body: some View {

        VStack {

            Button(action: {
                self.showPopUp = true
            }) {
                Text("Show PopUp Button")
            }

            Spacer()

            if self.showPopUp == true {
                PopUp(showPopUp: $showPopUp)
            }
        }
    }
}


struct PopUp: View {
    @Binding var showPopUp: Bool

    var body: some View {

        ZStack {

            Color.orange

            Button(action: {
                self.showPopUp.toggle()
            }) {
                Text("Hide PopUp Button")
            }
        }.frame(width: 300, height: 500, alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for answering!
Did you mean there is a more efficient way of doing this when you said "@Binding is indeed a possibility to solve this."  ?
Just curious

Comment: Thanks for that!
Yes, I was just waiting for the 8 minute time time-out to get over, done!